# how to store the values into data table which are entered in grid view?

Tags: c#, datagrid

I want to insert the values entered in data grid view in a data table..
I tried with code..

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   billNO++;
   if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) { con.Close(); }
   con.Open();
   string s = "CREATE TABLE [" + "" + combCustomerName.Text + "] (SlNO int Not Null , ItemDesc varchar(100) , ItemDetails varchar(100) , UMO varchar(10) , Quntity numeric(10,3) , Rate numeric(10,2) , Amount numeric(10,2) , GrossTot numeric(10,2) , Discount numeric(7,2) , Taxpc numeric(5,2) , TaxAmt numeric(5,2) , OtherAmt numeric(7,2) , NetAmt numeric(10,2))";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   //string insert=null;
   SqlCommand inscmd = new SqlCommand();
   for (int i = 0; i < datagridItemEntry.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      inscmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [" + "" + combCustomerName.Text + "] VALUES(" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value.ToString() + "','" + datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value.ToString() + "')";
   }

   if (inscmd.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Done!");
   }
   con.Close();
}
```

It is creating the table..
I am getting exception as Index out of range while inserting..
Help me out.

Comment: _" I tried with code.."_ ... _"Help me out."_ I'm missing something, for example the  problem with your code.

Comment: You should explain what is the problem faced in this code.

Comment: I wonder how that code will work!!!

You are creating table each time you click the Save button!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Copy Paste this code after your first query got executed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagridItemEntry.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string query1 = "insert into "+combCustomerName.Text+" values(" + gvSalesInv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "," + gvSalesInv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "," + gvSalesInv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "," + gvSalesInv.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "," + gvSalesInv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + "," + gvSalesInv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value + "," + gvSalesInv.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value + "," + gvSalesInv.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value + "," + gvSalesInv.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value + "," + gvSalesInv.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value + "," + gvSalesInv.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value + "," + gvSalesInv.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value + ")";
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
```